Topological continuity of a circle parametrization
A canonical example of a map between topological spaces that is continuous and bijective, but whose inverse is not continuous (thus preventing it from being a homeomorphism) is a parametrisation of a circle $f: [0,1)\to \mathbb{S}^1, f(x) = (cos(2\pi x), sin(2\pi x))$.

However, I struggle to see how this map is even continuous. The topological definition of continuity is that the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ of any open set $U$ is open. But if I take $U$ to be the arc of $\mathbb{S}^1$ containing the 'cut', its preimage should be the disjoint union of left and right ends of a half-open unit segment, and thus it cannot be open (as shown below).


I believe the answer to be very simple. Thanks!

The disjoint union of left and right ends of a half-open unit segment is open in the half open unit segment (even though it is not open in $\mathbb{R}$). Perhaps you should recall the definition of the subspace topology.

You can also argue that the two coordinate functions are continuous.

The preimage of an open set by a continuous map must be open in the domain. In this case, $[0,1)$ has the topology induced by $\mathbb{R}$, that is, open sets in $[0,1)$ are open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ intersected with $[0,1)$.
In the example you show above, the left set could be represented as $$[0,1)\cap ((-a,c)\cup (b,d))$$ for some $a>0, d>1$, with that second set open in $\mathbb{R}$.
